# HTML -- data-content-field

Tags: html, seo

I noticed on a website that within a h1, they had a `data-content-field` so the code was

```
<h1 data-content-field="site-title">
    My Amazing Website
</h1>
```

Is there any need in the data-content-field? I've personally never used it before. I've heard that it can be good for SEO and Google's bots when it comes to indexing websites.

I've seen them been used on other tags as well as the site title.

Would it hurt my site if I were to add / remove it (especially for SEO).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no. You're missing the point.

All `data-` attributes are custom attributes the can be added by the user. For example in my applications I use `data-id`, `data-int` and some others.

The advantage is that you can put here your own attributes. Please note that the **`data-`** tag is supported in **HTML5 and above.**

There is no connection between `data-content-field` and SEO.

I hope it helps you! Read some tutorials about SEO, they will probably make you a better programmer/webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

All data-* attributes are for internal use within a page or site, basically in client-side scripting, site specific search systems and things like that. General search engines should be expected to ignore them. The example you mention looks rather misguided, among other things because h1 is meant to be page-specific, not site-specific and because here a class attribute would intuitively look more suitable - but in the absence of an address of the page, this is just an educated guess.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I get what it's for now!